# Has the Doctor appeared in Torchwood or The Sarah Jane Adventures?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood, the-sarah-jane-adventures

I'm wondering if the Doctor has appeared in any episodes of [Torchwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchwood) or [The Sarah Jane Adventures](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0862620/).

I know that I could look through the IMDB episode list or the Wikipedia pages, but those contain a lot of spoilers that I would prefer to avoid, so please also avoid spoilers in your answers.

Comment: Torchwood,season 2, Episode 10, Capaldi plays an underhanded politician... So, not yet Doctor 12 but pretty close...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there have been appearances of the Doctor in *The Sarah Jane Adventures*:

- The 10th Doctor appears in the two-part [The Wedding of Sarah Jane Smith](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1498160/).
- The 11th Doctor appears in the two-part [Death of the Doctor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1679512/).

The Doctor has not (so far) made any appearance in *Torchwood*, although characters from Torchwood have appeared in Doctor Who:

- Captain Jack Harkness appeared first in *Doctor Who*.
- The Torchwood team appear in [The Stolen Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1205437/) / [Journey's End](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1205438/) two part story.
- The *Captain Jack's Monster Files* webcast featured Captain Jack profiling *Doctor Who* monsters/aliens, but at the Torchwood Hub.

The 10th Doctor's companion, Martha Jones, has appeared in Torchwood in [Reset](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1160002/), [Dead Man Walking](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1186346/), and [A Day in the Death](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1186345/). The TARDIS also appeared in [End of Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0912349/), and the Doctor may have been inside (but he never appeared on screen).

The Doctor's severed hand (from [The Christmas Invasion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562994/)) was found by Captain Jack and appeared in several Torchwood episodes, from the first (Everything Changes) until it was taken by the Master in [Utopia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1000259/).

Comment: Presumably there will be no more episodes of *The Sarah Jane Adventures* (since Elisabeth Sladen has passed away), so there will be no more crossovers there.  *Torchwood* was created by Russell T Davies, who is no longer executive producer for *Doctor Who*, so it's likely that there won't be more crossovers in the near future there, either.

Comment: I don't think the fact that RTD is no longer involved in Doctor Who necessarily means there will never be crossovers with Torchwood - after all, they're still both made by BBC Wales. However, the fact that the two universes seem to be diverging may well mean that.

Comment: One note: You could say The Doctor technically appeared once in Torchwood at the end of the episode "End of Days". He wasn't seen but in the episode you could hear the TARDIS landing and Jack runs off to find the doctor.

Comment: @AlanBarber the TARDIS appeared.  The Doctor did not.

Comment: Actually, the tenth doctor's hand appears in several episodes of Torchwood. It's Jack's "Doctor Detector", the hand in a jar.

Comment: The Doctor has never appeared in Torchwood, and probably never will. Steven Moffat has specifically said that he and Russell Davies do not want children wanting to watch Torchwood because of The Doctor appearing in it.

Comment: @BenjaminFranz  I had heard the same thing, and feel that is a definitive answer to the 'Torchwood' side of the question..  Dr Who has never and *will never* appear in Torchwood.

Comment: The Doctor's Tardis sound has appeared in Torchwood as well.

Comment: It's worth noting that several Torchwood episodes also referred to the Doctor, even though he didn't appear.  There were several references by Jack in early episodes to "finding the right doctor" to fix his immortality.  In the first episode with Martha, they allude to the assumption that the Doctor must have influenced UNIT to hurry through her medical doctorate.  And in Children of the Earth, Gwen posits that the times the Doctor *doesn't* come save the planet, it must be because he's ashamed of humanity.

Answer (score 1):

I recall seeing him in The wedding of Sarah Jane and The death of the Doctor

Comment: This was already mentioned in the accepted answer.